# jQuery Scroll After Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me?

code before :

```
return $(window).scroll(function() {
  angular.element(":focus").blur();
  return angular.element("div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu").hide();
});
```

code I make :

```
$(startDateEl).on('click', function(){
  $("div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu").focusin().on('scroll', function(){
    $("div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu").hide();
  });
});
```

The problem is when in phone scroll it hide keyboard because it using window.
this using directive angular and custom date. after to next page this windows scroll event function always active, and then I refactor the code what I want to question is how to make this run sequential after .focus() to datepicker and then the .scroll() function active to hide datepicker

or how to .scroll() without using target element window?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is

// for desktop

```
            $("div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu").on('mouseleave', function(){
              $("div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu").hide();
              $(startDateEl).blur();
            });
```

// for mobile

```
    $("#main").bind('touchmove', function(){
      $("div.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu").hide();
      $(startDateEl).blur();
    });
```